# Differences between to + inf and v-ing

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, gerunds

What differences between two sentences below:

```
The solution for this problem is to use another type of mapping
```

and

```
The solution for this problem is using another type of mapping
```

And in general, what differences between using "to + inf" and "v-ing"?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is ambiguous.

Let's say there's a man who can solve all our problems, he's our 'perfect solution'. We want to use him for our project, but he's not available because he's using another type of mapping.

Comment: That's funny. :-) By the way, I had to read it three times before I can wrap my head around the fact that "The solution for this problem" is in fact a man in the alternate interpretation.

Comment: It's often used sarcastically. Imagine this conversation: "I bought a dog so we have the perfect defense against burglars!" "Yeah? Well your 'perfect defense' is sleeping by the fire, snoring."

Comment: @DamkerngT., it's like the motto "our business is working for you" - you can read it two ways. (0: You can construe **is** as a marker of progressive aspect.